# Losy comparison between dates

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, comparison

Is there a way I can make MySQL return `1` instead of `0` for `SELECT NOW() = '2016-10-10'` without casting (`CAST('2016-10-10' AS DATE)`) or converting to date (`DATE('2016-10-10')`).

My real case scenario is a comparison between a `DATE` and a `DATETIME` column. I want to `JOIN` on those columns, but that's possible only if I can make MySQL compare only the date, ignoring the time.

I can't do the cast/convert because that is very expensive ( [Slow query performance left joining a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943442/slow-query-performance-left-joining-a-view) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the `'2016-10-10'` string that you need to cast (since it is a [valid date literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html)), but `NOW()`.

`NOW()` returns your current timestamp, with hours, minutes and seconds. While `'2016-10-10'` is interpreted as `'2016-10-10 00:00:00'`. Which, presumably is not equal to the current time.

So

```
SELECT DATE(NOW()) = '2016-10-10'
```

**UPD**:

> I can make MySQL compare only the date, ignoring the time.

For the comparison `coldate = coldatetime` you can compare on range, like:

```
coldate <= coldatetime AND coldate + INTERVAL 1 DAY > coldatetime
```

Depending on your actual case it may or may not be beneficial.

Comment: Indeed, I explained myself badly, the casting is on the left side of the equal sign. But please re-read the second part of my question.